# How to create a foreignkey reference with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Hi I am not able to understand how to make a foreignkey reference using sqlalchemy. I have created a new table client in my database:

```
class Client(DeclarativeBase):

    __tablename__ = 'client'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    user_id = Column(
        Integer,
        ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
        nullable=False,
        index=True,
    )

    orgname = Column(Unicode, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Client, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Not I am trying to do something like this

```
 u = User(user_name=u'dusual')
 session.add(u)
 c = Client(user=u, orgname="dummy_org")
 session.add(c)
```

But sqlalchemy shouts back saying :

(k, cls_.**name**))
TypeError: 'user' is an invalid keyword argument for Client

Now shouldn't this be obvious that user should be allowed as a keyword argument how can I make sure my table is able to take user keyword argument.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to define a [relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#orm-tutorial-relationship) between `User` and `Client` models:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class Client(DeclarativeBase):

    __tablename__ = 'client'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    user_id = Column(
        Integer,
        ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
        nullable=False,
        # no need to add index=True, all FKs have indexes
    )
    user = relationship('User', backref='clients')

    orgname = Column(Unicode, nullable=False)

    # no need to add a constructor
```

Then you can associate instances of `User` and `Client` models in two ways - either by assigning an integer to `Client.user_id`:

```
u = User(user_name=u'dusual')
session.add(u)
session.flush()  # to make sure the id is fetched from the database
c = Client(user_id=u.id, orgname="dummy_org")
session.add(c)
```

or by assinging a `User` instance to `Client.user`.

```
u = User(user_name=u'dusual')
# no need to flush, no need to add `u` to the session because sqlalchemy becomes aware of the object once we assign it to c.user
c = Client(user=u, orgname="dummy_org")
session.add(c)
```

Actually, there's a third way - since we've configured a `backref` on `Client.user`, SQLAlchemy added a list-like `clients` attribute to our `User` model:

```
u = User(user_name=u'dusual')
u.clients.append(Client(orgname="dummy_org"))
session.add(u)
```

Comment: Well , Explicitly declaring a relationship works. But I was wondering if there is an implicit way in which this works because it seems to work for some of the code I was looking at for reference

Comment: I tried the 2nd method you explained, but got an error 1364: "Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value". I wonder how to deal with this error. The database that I'm using is MySQL.

Comment: Note that whether a ForeignKey index is created for you automatically depends on which database you are using. In the case of sqlite3 it's not automatically created for you but it is highly recommended that you do.

Comment: Amazing. This is 8 years old and answered so many questions I've had for so long. I wish I could upvote 10 times.

Comment: @JasonStrimpel: I'm glad you found it useful

Answer (score 1):

For everyone that came here like me with need of solving that problem dynamically, here it is:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class Client(Base):
    __tablename__ = "client"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # No relationship, not foreign key
    user_id = Column(Integer)
```

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.sql.ddl import AddConstraint
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import ForeignKeyConstraint, MetaData, Table

name = "client_user_id_fkey"
fk = ForeignKeyConstraint((Client.user_id,), (User.id,), name=name)
# We need to assign that foreign key to proper table
Table(Client.__table__.name, MetaData(), fk)
# Adding a contraint
session.execute(AddConstraint(fk))
session.commit()
# With that FK existed we can add relationship through the mapper 
Client.__mapper__.add_property("user", relationship(User, backref="clients"))
```

Now it works:

```
u = User()
t = Client(user=u)
session.add(t)
session.commit()
```